# How to access the value stored within a memory address using GDB

Tags: linux

So I understand the assembly code and what it does. I need to compare (%rdi)with 0x0, so I need to know the what is exactly (%rdi) and how to access it using debugger gdb. From my understanding, %rdi is the register, placing a parenthesis means the content stored in this register is a memory address, and calling of (%rdi) will return the content stored in the memory address which is pointed by the register. Am I right? If so, how do type in the terminal to access this value? I have attached disassembled code.

Dump of assembler code for function phase_1:

```
   0x0000000000400f6d <+0>:     push   %rbx
   0x0000000000400f6e <+1>:     mov    %rdi,%rbx
   0x0000000000400f71 <+4>:     cmpb   $0x0,0x1(%rdi)
   0x0000000000400f75 <+8>:     jne    0x400f7e <phase_1+17>
   0x0000000000400f77 <+10>:    cmpb   $0x6a,(%rbx)
   0x0000000000400f7a <+13>:    jne    0x400f85 <phase_1+24>
   0x0000000000400f7c <+15>:    pop    %rbx
   0x0000000000400f7d <+16>:    ret    
   0x0000000000400f7e <+17>:    call   0x4016ed <explode_bomb>
   0x0000000000400f83 <+22>:    jmp    0x400f77 <phase_1+10>
   0x0000000000400f85 <+24>:    call   0x4016ed <explode_bomb>
   0x0000000000400f8a <+29>:    jmp    0x400f7c <phase_1+15>
```

I tried to use gdb x $rdi, it just shows Cannot access memory address at 0x0

I think I should rephrase my question: How do I access all the memory address with their corresponding values? I need to find that specific memory address that stores 0x6b and following memory address should store 0x0.

Comment: Try `p $rdi` first; maybe `%rdi` really is zero.  If so then you have a bug at some earlier point.

Comment: Normally, `x/b $rdi` should indeed display the byte whose address is in `%rdi`.  The message suggests however that this address is zero.  (Are you already running the program, and have got it to this point in the code by single-stepping or a breakpoint?  Maybe you could post a complete transcript of your gdb session.)

Comment: To make `gdb` really useful for debugging assembly, start `gdb` and type `starti`, `layout asm` and `layout reg` and you will be given a graphical (top like) view of what is in every register.  (then `stepi` as normal) I also like `display/i $pc` to display the current command to be executed.